# Is it possible to Install keyboard language on windows phone 7 Emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

Is it possible to install different languages keyboards like Urdu, Hindi or Persian on Windows phone 7 emulator. I have an app which has all these languages and I want to test it on different inputs but I can't find a way to install these languages on emulator.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try changing the region or the language of the emulator?

Comment: yes that doesn't work.. Some by default keyboard languages are there but that doesn't include these languages

Answer (score 0):

Currently you don't have any option to install keyboards on Emulator.